# sIFR not working. I'm using test files on zip

Tags: sifr

Im trying to use sIFR but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have a h1 and a h3 and I can't see it.

here is my website: http://www.franciscosamper.com/andcompany

I'm using tradegothic.swf with color #CCCCCC and I can't view it. If you check code I have all includes done.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery sIFR. Try using the official release instead.